# Relational Data Model into Dimensional Data Model

Tags: database, relational-database, data-warehouse, dimensions, dimensional-modeling

I have created the Dimensional Data Model and later on I have realized that I have no relation in it... I hope You can help me!

Let me explain what I did. I took data from Relational Model (one that contains primary/foreign keys and their relations and some table contains same parameters, that indicates their relations) and put it into Dimensional Data Model

To copy data from Relational to Dimensional Data model I have used simple Insert Select. Of course I do some data manipulation such as extraction and so.

```
INSERT INTO...
SELECT sequence.nextval, param1, param2,...
FROM
(SELECT ...);
```

And this results me in a "solution" with no relations in my Dimensional Model, because I just select needed parameters and put into the Dimensional Model.

All sources are within Oracle Database, and I am implementing the Dimensional Model in Oracle as well.

Below there is a sample of part of the system.

[image]

What would be the right way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean? Are there no proper Key values in factTrip?

Comment: There may be, but I am not able to find them, I am not sure how to make it right... because at some point I lose all the links between facts and dimensions

Comment: You generated values of the surrogate keys in the dimension tables, right? When loading the fact table, did you perform lookups to replace business keys with the surrogate ones?

Comment: Marek, right! I see what I am missing now.... I need to replace business keys with the surrogate keys. Is there a good explanation how to do this in the right way?

Comment: Since you are not using a dedicated ETL tool, load the dimensions to generate the surrogate keys and then join them to the Trip table on business keys when loading factTrip to get measures from Trip and surrogate keys from the dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution looks a mess.

You need this:

DimTrain, DimStearsMan, DimDate (grain day), DimTime (second grain for 24hours), factTript.

They you create 4 views: DimDepartureDate, DimDepartutetime, DimArrivalDate, DimArrivaltime (your tool might do it for you; hence you might not require views). Oh you also need scrips (or something else to fill the DimTime and DimDate with all the possible combinations, it might be a good idea to fill the DimDate with 10 or 20 years of dates).

You should use only surrogate keys to join tables (and also keep the business ids in the tables, your users might want go to the operational system inspect the data).

Then you create the factTrip and you join it to the Dimensions using the surrogate keys (also known as dimensional keys) and add the duration metrics ti the factTrip. This is, 6 foreign keys + metrics.